# <a></a> auto reference page url inside of <a></a> tag

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, find, href

How do I reference the current page URL?

I have a share twitter button on several pages. I would like to be able to automatically refernce the current page URL so when a user clicks "tweet this page" the URL is generated in the twitter tweet box. The reason I wish to do this is so I can manage the button from one place and not several pages.

HTML (currently, the url is manually pasted into the href tag in the  link.

```
<a href="http://dangfoods.com/coconutchips.php" title="These chips are great for you HEALTH!! #dangfoods" class="tweetDialog" target="_blank"><div id="tweets-btn" class="custom-button">Tweet This Page</div></a>
```

Current Javascript

```
// We bind a new event to our link
$('a.tweetDialog').click(function(e){
  //We tell our browser not to follow that link
  e.preventDefault();
  //We get the URL of the link
  var loc = $(this).attr('href');
  //We get the title of the link
  var title  = escape($(this).attr('title'));
  //We trigger a new window with the Twitter dialog, in the middle of the page
  window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + title + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry about that @ComFreek, I'm trying to reference the URL so when the user clicks the twitter button, the URL is automattically placed into the dialog pop box. Currently, for each page I have to manually put the URL in the href attribute. I'd rather have it where I can manage one button globally, instead for each page.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use current page URL instead of `href` attribute? Change

```
var loc = $(this).attr('href');
```

to

```
var loc = location.href;
```

Or you could generate Twitter share URL server-side, put it in `href` attribute, then in onclick stop default handler and open window with link target. That way your link would work without JavaScript.

Comment: This was helpful. Turned out I just needed to put "window.location.href". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "location.href" to get URL of the page and "document.title" to get the title of the current page. Try this:

```
$('a.tweetDialog').click(function(e){
    //We tell our browser not to follow that link
    e.preventDefault();

    //We get the URL of the link
    var loc = location.href;
    //We get the title of the link
    var title  = escape(document.title);

    //We trigger a new window with the Twitter dialog, in the middle of the page
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url=' + loc + '&text=' + title + '&', 'twitterwindow', 'height=450, width=550, top='+($(window).height()/2 - 225) +', left='+$(window).width()/2 +', toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, directories=0, scrollbars=0');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the title is a feature, however, the location.href doesn't put the link inside the twitter dialog box. If you visit www.dangfoods.com/coconutchips.php you'll see what I'm trying to achieve, but without having to manually edit the button on each page.

Comment: This was helpful, turns out just needed "window.location.href" for it to work. Thanks!